# Почему IDE выдаёт предупреждение "устаревшая версия" при использовании new Integer()?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printNumber(new Integer(112)); // обычный int, даже без переменной
    }

    public static void printNumber(int i) {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели число " + i);
    }
}
```

`printNumber(new Integer(112));` - зачеркивает и пишет устаревшая версия, как в это примере сделать правильно и без устаревшей версии?
Так:???

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 223;
        printNumber(i);
    }

    public static void printNumber(int i) {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели число " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите заголовки так, чтобы они передавали суть вопроса. Желательно формулировать их в вопросительной форме.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хорошо, извиняюсь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> @Deprecated(since="9")
>   public Integer​(int value)
>
> **Deprecated.** *It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory `valueOf(int)` is generally a better choice, as it is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.*
>
> Constructs a newly allocated Integer object that represents the
>   specified int value.

Используйте фабричный метод [Integer.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) вместо конструктора.